# how set set attribute ('primaryVisibility') in override.AbsOverride maya 2018 or 2019

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, maya-api

**how set set attribute ('primaryVisibility') in override.AbsOverride   maya 2018 or 2019**

```
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup
import maya.cmds as cmds

rs = renderSetup.instance()    
# Create render layer

r1 = rs.createRenderLayer("char_beauty")


# Create collections

c1 = r1.createCollection("char")

c2 = r1.createCollection("trk_geo")

c2pv=c2.createCollection("PV")

c2pv.getSelector().setFilterType(2)


so=c2.createOverride('PV', override.AbsOverride.kTypeId)
```

**so.setattribute('primaryVisibility')**

try to create primaryVisibility attribute.. for trk_geo collection ..don't know set primaryVisibility attribute in AbsOverride .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is missing a `finalize` method call on the override:

```py
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup
import maya.cmds as cmds

rs = renderSetup.instance()    

# Create render layer
r1 = rs.createRenderLayer("char_beauty")

# Create collections
c1 = r1.createCollection("char")
c2 = r1.createCollection("trk_geo")
c2pv=c2.createCollection("PV")
c2pv.getSelector().setFilterType(2)

# Create override
so = c2.createOverride('PV', override.AbsOverride.kTypeId)
so.finalize('visibility')
```

If you don't know the name of the attribute, you may skip the last `finalize` call, then assign the override manually by drag-and-dropping the attribute from the Attribute Editor and then call the `print so.attributeName()` to see the actual name.